# searchable file content wordpress

Tags: wordpress, file, searchable

I am building a wordpress site and I have many files I need to upload and these files need the content to be searchable for users. Right now they are in pdf format. (format does not matter as long as these files can not be altered)

example: If the user types in a keyword or phrase the file content will be searched and return the file to the user that the keyword matched.

I searched for solutions and came up empty, maybe someone can point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Its preety simple, you just have to install pdftotext [(here is a good tutorial)](https://davidwalsh.name/read-pdf-doc-file-php) and then you can search for any text. So if you a have a list of all your documents in an array you can loop and search for a certain string.

I have not tested this code, but i guess it should work fine.

```
<?php 
$files = array('relative-link-to-file1', 'relative-link-to-file2', 'file3');
$text_to_search = 'test';
$found = array();

foreach($files as $file){
    $content = shell_exec('/usr/local/bin/pdftotext '.$file.' -');
    $found[]['position'] = strpos($content, $text_to_search );
    $found[]['file'] = $file;
}
// To echo all the found instances.
foreach($found as $file){
    echo 'The text has been found at position '.$file['position'].' within the file '.$file['file'];
}
?>
```

Comment: Thanks! I will give it a shot and let you know :)